# How is done the calculation of the minimum number of movement to solve any configuration of Rubik's Cube?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

I have read a few weeks ago that some mathematical researchers have discover that the minimum number of movements to solve any initial configuration of a Rubik's cube has been downsized to 20.

How do they calculate such a number ?

Thanks.

Comment: Technically there is no maximum length as you could sit there wasting your time doing a move, then as your next move undo your previous move.  I think you mean theminimum number of moves to solve the Rubik's cube over all possible initial conditions.  If you can find a textbook like "The Handbook of Cubik Math" that would be a start.  There is a little bit of a subject called "group theory" involved but not too much.

Comment: That's totally right, I meant minimum instead of maximum. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the discussion and references on the associated Wikipedia page [Optimal solutions for Rubik's Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube)

Comment: Did not notice that there was such a page on wikipedia. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.cube20.org/